# Make character fall or jump off of platform and to the same y coordinate they started in?

Tags: python, pygame

I am in the process of making a simple game by learning Pygame. Below I have a demo of my code:

> I put a hitbox around both the platform and the character because I am using images, but in my example here I simplified it just so I can get assistance with the problem. I need to be able to have the character jump onto the platform. If they are directly above the platform, they need to be able to jump and land back down on it. If they walk or jump off of the side of the platform, they need to fall to the y coordinate they jumped from.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walk_count = 0
        self.is_jumping = False
        self.jump_count = 10
        self.standing = False
        self.idle = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 10, self.y + 15, 50, 47)

    def draw(self, win):
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 10, self.y + 15, 50, 47)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox, 2)

    def land(self):
        self.y = stick.hitbox[0] - self.hitbox[0]
        self.is_jumping = False
        self.jump_count = 10
        self.x = 800
        self.y = 410 - self.height + 4

class Platform(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 104, 5, 2)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, 104, 5))
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 104, 2)


# DRAW FUNCTION
def redraw_game_window():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    stick.draw(win)
    george.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


# MAIN LOOP
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 32, True)
stick = Platform(800, 410)
george = Player(50, 525, 64, 64)
running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(27)

    if george.is_jumping:
        if george.hitbox[0] + george.hitbox[2] < stick.hitbox[0] + stick.hitbox[2] and george.hitbox[0] + george.hitbox[2] > stick.hitbox[0]:
            if george.hitbox[1] + george.hitbox[3] < stick.hitbox[1] and george.hitbox[1] + george.hitbox[3] > 390:
                george.land()
                print('land')
    if george.jump_count == 10 and george.y == 410 - george.height + 4:
        if george.hitbox[0] + george.hitbox[2] < stick.hitbox[0] or george.hitbox[0] > stick.hitbox[0] + stick.hitbox[2]:
            george.is_jumping = True
            george.jump_count = -10

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and george.x > george.vel:
        george.x -= george.vel
        george.left = True
        george.right = False
        george.standing = False
        george.idle = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and george.x < 1200 - (george.width + george.vel):
        george.x += george.vel
        george.left = False
        george.right = True
        george.standing = False
        george.idle = False
    else:
        george.walk_count = 0
        george.standing = True

    if not(george.is_jumping):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            george.is_jumping = True
            george.walk_count = 0
            george.idle = False
    else:
        if george.jump_count >= -10:
            george.y -= (george.jump_count * abs(george.jump_count)) * 0.5
            george.jump_count -= 1
            george.standing = False
        else:
            george.is_jumping = False
            george.jump_count = 10

    redraw_game_window()

pygame.quit()
```

I was able to work out how to get the character to land on the platform and feel like I am getting close to having them fall or jump off, but they don't fall all the way down and cannot get back onto the platform either.

Comment: Is stick a global variable? You reference it in your Player.land() method, but it is neither passed as a parameter nor declared global. Although I admit that this probably won't solve your issue, but you should change it anyway, maybe it does help.

Comment: stick is an instance of the Platform class that is declared along with the Player instance, george, within the main loop!

Answer (score 1):

simple, just read the following code (comments provided)

```py
# set the following variables
# the jump height is, you know the jump height
JUMP_HEIGHT = 20
# gravity, affects jump height and speed of downfall
GRAVITY = 1
# the number subtracted every frame, equal to jump height as of now
Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT
# the trigger for jump, initially false
isJump = False

# set the isJump variable to True when jump key is pressed, nothing else
# add this function to mainloop, just call this before blitting stuff
def jump():
    # if jump is triggered, do this
    if isJump:
        # subtract the y_velocity from player y every frame
        player_y -= Y_VELOCITY
        # also make the gravity affect yvelocity for realistic effect and free fall (in negative)
        Y_VELOCITY -= GRAVITY
        # if player reached the initial spot, do this
        if Y_VELOCITY <= -JUMP_HEIGHT - GRAVITY:
            # cancel the trigger
            isJump = False
            # reset the variables
            Y_VELOCITY = JUMP_HEIGHT
```

if the above code does not work as expected,

```py
# replace this line
if Y_VELOCITY <= -JUMP_HEIGHT - GRAVITY:
# with this
if Y_VELOCITY < -JUMP_HEIGHT - GRAVITY:
```

i am not good at explaning stuff